# PHP explode comma separated values and then email addresses

Tags: php

I have a string in a database of email address that i need to split down:

123@test.domain.com, ff@g.com

I am exploding the addresses by comma and then trying to explode each email address to get the part after the @ symbol

```
$toAddresses = explode(',', $result["to_addresses"]);
foreach($toAddresses as $a) {
$toAddresses2 = explode('@', $a);
    foreach($toAddresses2 as $b) {
        echo $b.'<BR>';
    }
}
```

and this is returning the following:

```
123
test.domain.com
ff
g.com
```

I want to be able to get just the part after the @ but not sure where I have gone wrong

Comment: `$toAddresses2 = explode('@', $a)[1]; echo $toAddresses2;` You only need the second index value. No need for second foreach

Comment: You could also use `list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $a); echo $domain;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try following:

```
$toAddresses = explode(',', $result["to_addresses"]);
foreach ($toAddresses as $a) {
    echo substr($a, 0, strpos($a, "@")) . "<br>"; // For get string before @
    echo substr($a, strpos($a, "@") + 1) . "<br>"; // For get string after @
}
```

In code above, **strpos** determine the location of `@` in email address and then **substr** cut the sub string after that position.

Read more about [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) & [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: this works great, within that foreach, can i also obtain the first part of the email address?

Comment: This is a nice clean solution.

Comment: @charlie Updated code for getting strings before and after @.

Answer (score 3):

remove foreach

write:
`echo $toAddresses2[1]."<br>";`

Answer (score 0):

This line: `$toAddresses2 = explode('@', $a);`

Will create an array similar to this: `["0": "ff", "1": "g.com"]`

So you can select the second value using index `1`, like so `$toAddresses2[1]`.

I would suggest testing if the value exists, in case any of the addresses in the string are invalid for any reason.

So it would be

```
echo isset($toAddresses2[1]) ? $toAddresses2[1] . "<br />" : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_slice() as example:-

```
$toAddresses = explode(',', $$result["to_addresses"]);
foreach($toAddresses as $a) {
    $toAddresses2 = explode('@', $a);
    foreach(array_slice($toAddresses2,1) as $b) {
        echo $b.'<BR>';
    }
}
```

array_slice($array, $index) will return the sliced array from the given index.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this
>       $toAddresses = explode(',', "123@test.domain.com,ff@g.com");
>       foreach($toAddresses as $k=>$a) {
>       $toAddresses2 = substr($a,strpos($a,'@' )+1);
>       echo $toAddresses2 ."\n";     }